Regular expression to extract text between square brackets & last string out of the square bracket
I am new to the regex and trying to write the RegEx for the below string.
[1] [2] [3] [] [5[any]] my text

I want something like
1
2
3

5[any]
my text

I have tried the /\[(.*?)\]/g but it not working with inner brackets & the last word outside of the brackets
https://regex101.com/r/NYvxMC/2

If there is only one level of nesting, \[([^\[\]]|\[[^\[\]]+\])+\] would work. See also this question.

@DuesserBaest, there would only one level inner bracket, how the last words which out of the bracket can be retrieved ?

wrap it in parenthesis

my text also should be matched there.

how do you know "my text" is one item?

it always would be one

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Try:
((?<=\[)(?:[^\[\]]|\[[^\[\]]+\])*(?=\])|(?<=\s)[\w\h:.,]+$)

See: regex101

Explanation

( ... ): capture result to group 1:

(?<=\[) ... (?=\]): either in between brackets:
(?: ... )*: match  0 or more times:

[^\[\]]:  either non brackets


|: or

\[ ... \]: brackets with
[^\[\]]+: non-brackets in between




|: or words at the end:

(?<=\s): check that a space is preceeding
[\w\h:.,]+: match word characters and horizontal space; here you can add more characters as needed



